# Обработка сообщений присланных пользователем в Telegram на Python

Tags: python, telebot, telegram

Добрый день. Для создания бота в Телеграме использую библиотеку [TeleBot](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI). Задача такая: задается вопрос, пользователь отвечает. Как получить строку этого ответа? Как я понял, Телеграм присылает это сообщение в виде JSON'a. Вот что выдает, когда я пишу `print(message)`. Как отсюда вычленить текст? Часть выдачи вырезал, но, думаю, суть понятна.

```
{'photo': None, 'location': None, 'pinned_message': None, 'entities': None, 'migrate_from_chat_id': None, 'document': None, 'date': 1480364732, 'video': None, 'caption': None, 'new_chat_title': None, 'content_type': 'text', 'forward_from': None, 'audio': None, 'text': 'NEED_TEXT_HERE', 'venue': None, 'message_id': 240, 'reply_to_message': None}
```

Пробовал это декодировать через библиотеку `json`:

```
with open(message, "r") as file:
    activity = json.load(file)
    print(activity.get("text"))
```

Выдает ошибку:

> File "C:/TelegramBot/bot.py", line 46, in set_activity
>       with open(message, "r") as file:
>
> TypeError: invalid file: `<telebot.types.Message object at 0x00000208F3225FD0>`

Пробую напрямую:

```
activity = json.load(message)
```

> File "C:/TelegramBot/bot.py", line 46, in set_activity
>       activity = json.load(message)
>
> File "C:\Users\FLEX\Anaconda3\lib\json__init__.py", line 265, in load
>       return loads(fp.read(),
>
> AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'read'

Как от типа `Message` получить текст?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашим объяснениям я понял, что в переменной `message` лежит `JSON`- строка, т.е. ответ. Зачем вы пытаетесь открыть его как файл? `with open(message, "r") as file`.

Что бы декодировать `JSON` достаточно этого: `activity = json.loads(message)`. Внимание: **json.loads**, а вы используете `load`, вот и ошибка.

`json.load` принимает `file-like object`, который имеет метод `read()`, для чтения строки он не подходит.

Comment: @Nick16, вам же жирным выделили, что не `load`, а `loads`.

Comment: Да, исправил, спасибо. Правда выскочила другая проблема, ошибка
the JSON object must be str, not 'Message'. Т.е. я ошибался насчет json'a? Тогда чем может быть то, что выдал print(message)? 
Если воспринимать как словарь т.е.
activity = first_message.get("text")
Выскакивает AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Nick16, а на прямую по ключам обращаться пробовали? `message["text"]`

Comment: @Klym Да, выдает AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Nick16, тогда попробуйте явно привести его к строке, а затем пытаться десереализовать: `activity = json.loads(str(message))`

Comment: @Klym, не помогло. В общем решил проблему. Оказалось текст можно получить обратившись к полю text этого сообщения. `message.text`

Но все равно, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Nick16, пожалуйста.